# Forwarding http:// to http://www. using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I would like to use .htaccess to point any calls to `http://example.com/` to `http://www.example.com` including whether a page is specified. That is, `http://example.com/contact.html` would redirect to to `http://www.example.com/contact.html`.

Can someone help with the syntax as I've tried different examples and it won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this, it'll work on any domain without editing:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

[Source](http://davidwalsh.name/no-www-using-htaccess-file)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

**Trivia:** If you are using an example or placeholder domain, please use `example.com`. This domain has been reserved specifically for this purpose in [RFC2606](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2606.txt).

Comment: This doesnt work unfortunately, it just stays on http://mydomain.com

Answer (score 0):

I've written a small Apache plugin that might be helpful here, it's called "RedirToServName" and can be found in my software dump at http://www.hogyros.de/download/ . Documentation is a bit lacking; in essence all it does is generate redirects if the host name is not the canonical hostname from the ServerName directive.

Granted, using a dedicated plugin for that seems like overkill, but I find that it leaves less room for misconfiguration, as the only configuration variable is a boolean to turn it on.